# Why TwitterKit didEncounterError (withMessage Invalid parameter not satisfying- error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am getting this error only on first sign-in. i.e when I click to twitter button I am redirecting to the browser to login. I am able to login and redirecting back to the application and also able to log the username. but error happen with in next few seconds. 
But no log on Crashlytics, no app crash or no additional log on Xcode log window.

I did integrate Twitter with fabric.
Xcode: 6.1.1 
iOS: 8.1, 7.1

My code on AppDelegate

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
     [[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"nm5TpIjmg254b3IeXunehW3Jm" consumerSecret:@"zRsulsIrOPZXU0VilTPsQjUsdtknojB73v5LGqKH6QZfTm60BR"]; 
     [Fabric with:@[TwitterKit, CrashlyticsKit]];
     return YES;
}
```

And on viewcontroller

```
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
```

/ Twitter login

```
-(void) twitterLogin {

    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion: ^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {

             NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
             // get user details from Twitter
            // [self getTwitterAccountInformation];

         }
         else {

             NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

         }

     }];


}


exact error: - [TwitterKit] didEncounterError:withMessage: Invalid parameter not satisfying: error
```

Comment: On which line , it is causing? or it is showing in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Actually didn't figured out the same. The control enters to the twitterLogin method and I get the success callback. And after a few moments the error happening.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution, I am very grateful if anyone can help on this.

Comment: Just check the solution posted.

Comment: @Vizllx - nothing worked, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are adding multiple kits to Fabric, but the implementation is wrong which may be causing the error, like

```
[Fabric with:@[TwitterKit, CrashlyticsKit]];
```

**SOLUTION**

So, while adding `CrashlyticsKit` , you are missing this line means you have to initialize `CrashlyticsKit` service, just add this before adding kits in Fabric:

```
[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:<your key>];
```

---

**DEBUGGING**

For debugging purpose check once by removing the kit from Fabric like this :

```
 [Fabric with:@[TwitterKit]];
```

and see whether you are getting the error or not.

Comment: I tried the same but no luck. I just included the CrashlyticsKit to find out the issue. The error I am getting is from, before inclusion of the  CrashLyticsKit. Also I just created a new project and integrated the twitter to test purpose. That one also shows the same issue.